# How to make columns and rows dynamically in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I am making a GUI desktop application using python3, PyQt5 in windows 7.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. when my application runs, it makes an empty table using QTableWidget. There're also four buttons.
2. When a user clicks the first button, the empty table gets 2 rows and 4 columns.
3. In this situation, if the  user clicks another button, the previous columns and rows are removed, and the table gets 10 columns and 20 rows.

I made a empty table, but **I don't know how to make columns and rows dynamically.**

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QTableWidget, QPushButton

class mainClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.tableWidget = tableManager()
        self.returnedTableWidget = self.tableWidget.makeTable(self)

        btnMaker = buttonManager()
        btnMaker.makeTestBtn(self)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 700, 600)
        self.show()


class buttonManager(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def makeTestBtn(self, parent):
        testBtn01 = QPushButton("2 X 4", parent)
        testBtn02 = QPushButton("4 X 8", parent)
        testBtn03 = QPushButton("8 X 16", parent)
        testBtn04 = QPushButton("16 X 32", parent)

        testBtn01.move(50, 450)
        testBtn02.move(200, 450)
        testBtn03.move(350, 450)
        testBtn04.move(500, 450)


class tableManager(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def makeTable(self, parent):
        self.tableMaker = QTableWidget(parent)
        self.tableMaker.setGeometry(50, 50, 600, 400)

        return self.tableMaker


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mc = mainClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I know there are `setRowCount()` and `setColumnCount()` methods in `QTableWidget` class. But I don't know how and where to use those methods in my code.

Comment: The new rows and columns should be empty ?

Comment: Thank you for reading my question, tmoreau. // No, in fact, If a user clicks the button, columns and rows are dynamically created and filled with data from database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to create rows and cols:
1 -fetch all your data from db
2 -use for statement as follows :

```
all_data = db.fetch
tbl = QtGui.QTableWidget(len(all_data),X) # X is The number of columns that you need  
header_labels = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4',...]  
tbl.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header_labels)
for row in all_data:
    inx = all_data.index(row)
    tbl.insertRow(inx)
    tbl.setItem(inx,Y,QTableWidgetItem(your data)) # Y is the column that you want to insert data
```

for example:

```
all_data = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
tbl = QtGui.QTableWidget(len(all_data),4)
header_labels = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4']
tbl.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header_labels)
for row in all_data:
    inx = all_data.index(row)
    tbl.insertRow(inx)
    tbl.setItem(inx,0,QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))
    tbl.setItem(inx,0,QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))
    tbl.setItem(inx,0,QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))
```

I hope it was useful
Of course, if I did not understand your question, I apologize

Comment: I made it! Your guide did great help! I connected click signal to function that made columns and rows using insertRow() and insertColumn(). Thank you masood!

ps.) Oh. in the setItem method you wrote, there must be one more parenthesis. > 3<